# Using module_invoke() and render() causes PHP warnings

Tags: blocks

From within a block, I've used the following PHP to add additional blocks inside it:

```
$content_search = module_invoke('search_api_page', 'block_view', 'content_search');
$user_search = module_invoke('search_api_page', 'block_view', 'user_search');

print render($content_search);
print render($user_search);
```

When I do so, I get the following warnings:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in element_children() (line 6541 of /var/www/mysite.dev/public_html/includes/common.inc).
>   Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line 5998 of /var/www/mysite.dev/public_html/includes/common.inc).
>   Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line 6008 of /var/www/mysite.dev/public_html/includes/common.inc).

It appears that the problem is tied to the *render()* function as I can call *print_r($content_search)* and everything looks good, but I can't render the blocks without these warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocks aren't render arrays, they're made up of a `subject` and `content` key.

You'll probably have better luck referring to those explicitly:

```
$content_search = module_invoke('search_api_page', 'block_view', 'content_search');
$user_search = module_invoke('search_api_page', 'block_view', 'user_search');

print render($content_search['content']);
print render($user_search['content']);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it -- I've never run into that problem before.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
$content_search = module_invoke('search_api_page', 'block_view', 'content_search');
$user_search = module_invoke('search_api_page', 'block_view', 'user_search');

print render($content_search['content']);
print render($user_search['content']);
```

or use another method:

```
$block = block_load($module, $delta);
$render_array = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
$output = drupal_render($render_array);
print $output;
```